# compare checksum of files between two remote servers

Tags: linux, command-line, remote, checksum

On my local box `"machineA"`, I have two folders `"/primary"` and `"/secondary"`. These two folders have some files in it. Now on the remote server `"machineB"` I have one folder `"/bat/snap/"` which contains lot of files.

All the files in `"/primary"` and `"/secondary"` folders in `"machineA"` should be there in `"machineB"` remote server in this directory `"/bat/snap/"`. Now I need to compare checksum of all files in `"/primary"` and `"/secondary"` folder on local box `"machineA"` with remote server in this directory `"/bat/snap/"`. If there is any mismatch in checksum then I want to report all those files that has issue in `"machineA"`

Do I need to use md5checksum here?

**Update**

This is the command I am running on `"machineA"`:

```
find /primary/ /secondary/ -type f | xargs md5sum | ssh machineB '(cd /bat/snap/ && md5sum -c)' | egrep -v 'OK$'
```

Below is the error I am getting and after that I stopped my above command. I checked both the servers and I can see this file is present so what's wrong then?

```
md5sum: /primary/abc_monthly_134_proc_7.data: No such file or directory
/primary/abc_monthly_134_proc_7.data: FAILED open or read
```

Comment: Do you have, or can you install, the [mtree](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/fmtree.8.html) program?

Comment: I am running Ubuntu and I have sudo access so I can install it but is it needed both on source and destination servers or just source?

Comment: It needs to read both sets of files. You don't have to install it on both servers if you can share one server's files to the other over the network.

Comment: Ok but I don't need to copy anything just compare the checksum of files that's all. And if anything mismatches then report all those files.

Comment: You just need to copy the mtree output file, which contains the filenames and checksums,  from one system to the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what the various `md*sum` files are written for.

On machine A:

`find primary secondary -type f | xargs md5sum > checksum.md5`

(copy file to machine B)

Machine B:

`md5sum -c checksum.md5`

**Edit**: Combined into a single command: `find primary secondary -type f | xargs md5sum | ssh machineB '(cd /location_on_B/ && md5sum -c)' | egrep -v 'OK$'`

(Another option is to tell `rsync` to run in dry-run mode with `--checksum`.)

Comment: Can it be done in one command and figure out which files are having issues? Because I want to run one command on local box "machineA" only if this is possible by any chance?

Comment: Also `"machineB"` which is a remote server will have lot of files. I mean they will have `"primary"` and `"secondary"` files for `"machineA"` along with lot of other files.

Comment: It will only check the files listed in the checksum listing. I just combined it into one command and even verified it on a personal machine.

Comment: If paths change, you'll need to do some perl/sed magic to manipulate the listing.

Comment: after running the command, I am getting an error. I updated my question with details and I am not sure whats wrong?

Comment: For some reason, it cannot read/find that file on the second machine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76354/discussion-between-user1950349-and-aaron-d-marasco).