# compare checksum of files between two servers

Tags: linux, bash, shell, checksum

I have to compare checksum of all files in `/primary` and `/secondary` folders in `machineA` with files in this folder `/bat/snap/` which is in remote server `machineB`. The remote server will have lots of file along with files we have in `machineA`.

- If there is any mismatch in checksum then I want to report all those files that have issues in `machineA` with full path and exit with non zero status code.
- If everything is matching then exit successfully.

I wrote one command (not sure whether there is any better way to write it) that I am running on `machineA` but its very slow. Is there any way to make it faster?

```
(cd /primary && find . -type f -exec md5sum {} +; cd /secondary && find . -type f -exec md5sum {} +) | ssh machineB '(cd /bat/snap/ && md5sum -c)'
```

Also it prints out file name like this `./abc_monthly_1536_proc_7.data: OK`. Is there any way by which it can print out full path name of that file on `machineA`?

Comment: Use [rsync](https://rsync.samba.org/) --dry-run

Comment: Previously: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/438825/compare-checksum-of-files-between-two-remote-servers

Comment: yeah its a follow up from previous question so that I can make it fast.

Comment: What do you mean by "very slow"? That's got to read all the data on both sides; is it going slower than that? Are you pegging the disks (try, e.g., `iostat -kyx 10` to see disk utilization every 10s; you may need to leave out `y` for older iostats)